# Remove objects within array with filter and every

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use angular material as UI framework and use the chip component. 
I filter the data (an array of objects) and that works quite well. 
The first chip entry gets the data from the database and the remaining chips filter the data. 
If I want to delete a chip, the original data should be displayed again.

I have two main function add() and remove(). With add, I am adding the chip n the list and filtering the data. Within the remove() function I am using the filter() and every() helper but the every() helper doesn't iterate through my chip list and my returning value is empty

```
search data: any;
searchDataTmp: any;
searchDataReqTmp: any;
searchFieldValue: any;

add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.searchFieldData.push({ name: value.trim() });

      if (this.searchFieldData.length > 1) {
        this.filterData(value);
      } else {
        this.requestData(value);
      }
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  filterData(item) {
    this.searchData = this.searchData.filter((val) => {
        return val.description.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
  requestData(inputValue) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.apiService.callDataFromSource(inputValue).subscribe((item: any) => {
      this.searchDataReqTmp = item;
      this.searchData = this.searchDataReqTmp;
      this.loading = false;
    });
}


  remove(data: any): void {
    // e.g. this.searchFieldData = ['BarackObama', 'Trump'];
    const index = this.searchFieldData.indexOf(data);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.searchFieldData.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if (this.searchFieldData.length > 0) {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataReqTmp.filter((val) => {
        return this.searchFieldData.every((item) => {
          return val.description.toLowerCase().includes(item.name.toString().toLowerCase());
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataTmp;
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <mat-form-field class="search-field">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let inp of searchFieldData" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(inp)">
        {{inp.name}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="Keyword..." [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
```

What is the problem and why my remove() function is not working?

My data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUzdl.png)

**SOLUTION**

```
  remove(data: any): void {

    const index = this.searchFieldData.indexOf(data);

    // Deleting chips
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.searchFieldData.splice(index, 1);
    }


    // Data from requested data and filtering
    if (index > 1) {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataReqTmp.filter((val) => {
        return val.description.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchFieldData[index - 1].name.toLowerCase());
      });
    }

    // Data from first request
    if (index === 1) {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataReqTmp;
    }

    // Data from first initialising - ngOnInit()
    if (index === 0) {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataTmp;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can pass index instead of data and filter the array using that index. If data is an object above logic won't work.

Comment: Or you can pass the description text and filter the array by using .includes()

Comment: remove(description): void {
      this.searchData = this.searchDataReqTmp.filter((data) => {
        return data.description.toLowerCase() !== description.toLowerCase();
      });
    }

Comment: Why don't remove it like this?
  remove(data: any): void {
      this.searchFieldData.splice(data, 1);
   }

But instead of data , pass the index of the data

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I think I found a solution for me. I have added this in my question above.